# this does not return object property (arrow, this)

Tags: javascript, object, return, this, arrow-functions

```
var std_obj = {
  activeEffect : 'fade',
  name : 'Jane',
  displayMe() {
    const doSomeEffects = () => {
      if (this.activeEffect === 'fade') { 
        console.log(this.name); // this.name have accesss and logs
        // return this.name --> gives undefined ? why can't I return?
      }
    };
    doSomeEffects();
  }
};
console.log(std_obj.displayMe());
```

// console.log(this.name) works but I cannot return this.name and I'm a bit frustrated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arrow functions will take the `this` of their declaration scope. That is why the `this` here will point to the object. But to see that value you will have to change your code like this:

```
var std_obj = {
  activeEffect : 'fade',
  name : 'Jane',
  displayMe() {
    const doSomeEffects = () => {
      if (this.activeEffect === 'fade') { 
        console.log(this.name); // this.name have accesss and logs
        return this.name; //uncomment this
      }
    };
    return doSomeEffects(); //if you do not use return statement, then it will by default return undefined
  }
};
console.log(std_obj.displayMe());
```

If you will not return anything from displayMe() or doSomeEffects() it will not show `undefined`. The reason is functions by default return `undefined`. To test this : just run `console.log("hello");` in dev console. This will show hello and undefined.

Note: If you use function expression instead of arrow functions, it will return undefined. That is the power of arrow functions.

Answer (score 2):

You're not returning from `displayMe`, you're returning from `doSomeEffects`. The final line of `displayMe` is `doSomeEffects()`, with no return value. You need `return doSomeEffects()`.

```
  displayMe() {
    const doSomeEffects = () => {
      if (this.activeEffect === 'fade') { 
        console.log(this.name); // this.name have accesss and logs
        return this.name  // return from `doSomeEffect`
      }
    };
    return doSomeEffects(); // return from `displayMe`
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure but I think

```
var std_obj = {
  activeEffect : 'fade',
  name : 'Jane',
  displayMe() {
    const doSomeEffects = () => {
      if (this.activeEffect === 'fade') { 
        console.log(this.name);
        return this.name
      }
    };
    return doSomeEffects();
  }
};
console.log(std_obj.displayMe());
```

this is what you're trying to do

`doSomeEffects` inside `displayMe` returns this.name and you're calling `displayMe`

am I right?

Comment: Yes, I forgot to add return so displayMe() didn't return anything, thank you